# Specify size and position of matchbox-keyboard when launching from command line or script

Tags: raspbian

Folks,

I am attempting to set up a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ running Raspbian Stretch and using LXDE as the window manager and the official 7" touchscreen in portrait mode to bring up a website in chromium and also bring up the matchbox-keyboard.  I have found out how to position and size the chromium window, but not how to position and size the matchbox-keyboard window.

Any ideas would be helpful.